# Passing multiple inputs to .bat file via Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file, parameter-passing

I'm having a problem passing some arguments through my python script to a test.bat file.

```
//test.bat
@echo off
:: Extracting and input arguments
set IP=%1
set PASS=%~2
set DIR=%~3

:: Setup logfile
set LOG_FILE="%cd%\testLog.log"
if exist %LOG_FILE% del %LOG_FILE%

echo -------------------------------------------------------- >> %LOG_FILE%
echo Date    :  %date% >> %LOG_FILE%
echo Time    :  %time% >> %LOG_FILE%
echo IP      :  %IP% >> %LOG_FILE%
echo PW      :  %PASS% >> %LOG_FILE%
echo PATH    :  %DIR% >> %LOG_FILE%
.....
```

test.py

```
p = subprocess.Popen('test.bat', stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
ipAdr = '127.0.0.1'
pasWD = 'root'
locPath = 'C:\repos\batTester'

p.stdin.write(bytes(ipAdr , 'ascii')) #IP
p.stdin.write(bytes(pasWD , 'ascii')) #password
p.stdin.write(bytes(locPath , 'ascii'))#directory
```

I see, that bath file is run correctly, because testLog.log file is created, but `IP`, `PW`, and `DIR` fields are empty, so the rest of the script can't be executed.
How should I pass multiple arguments to a .bat file using a python script?

Comment: BTW, you can change that entire batch file to this, which is more efficient. 1. `@(Echo --------------------------------------------------------`, 2. `Echo Date    :  %DATE%`, 3. `Echo Time    :  %TIME`, 4. `Echo IP      :  %~1`, 5. `Echo PW      :  %~2`, 6. `Echo PATH    :  %~3) 1> "testLog.log"`. There is no need to define environment variables for the input arguments, _(as those are already saved to argument variables)_, or to open a file, write to it, and then close it, for every single `echo` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run `subprocess.run`:

```
p = subprocess.run(['test.bat', ipAdr, pasWD, locPath])
```

Comment: Thanks ;) I have one more question. The file test.bat connects to a specified IP address, but if the host is unreachable the whole application freezes for quite a long time. Is there any easy way to avoid this? The only thing I can think of is running the 'subprocess' as a separate thread.

Comment: You have a [`timeout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) parameter.